# Can't build release app, gradle says can't find enclosing method 'boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(android.view.Menu)

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

In debug mode the app runs smoothly, but when trying to build on release mode, the app build fails.

It gives me an error saying
`com.karriapps.smartsiddur.LocationsActivity$3: can't find enclosing method 'boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(android.view.Menu)' in program class com.karriapps.smartsiddur.LocationsActivity`

But I have no use of menu inside this activity now. I used to have beofre, but I removed it.

```
package com.karriapps.smartsiddur;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.DefaultItemAnimator;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.SearchView;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;

import com.karriapps.smartsiddur.fragments.LocationSearchFragment;
import com.karriapps.smartsiddur.model.ElavationService;
import com.karriapps.smartsiddur.model.Location;
import com.karriapps.smartsiddur.model.listeners.LocationListener;
import com.karriapps.smartsiddur.model.response.LocationResponse;
import com.karriapps.smartsiddur.util.LocationHandler;
import com.karriapps.smartsiddur.util.SSApp;
import com.karriapps.smartsiddur.views.LocationViewHolder;

import org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull;

import java.util.List;

import io.realm.RealmResults;


public class LocationsActivity extends BaseActivity implements LocationSearchFragment.LocationSetListener {

    public static final String BUNDLE_LOCATION_ID = "location_id";
    public static final String BUNDLE_FROM_SEARCH = "from_search";
    public static final int RESPONSE_OK = 0;
    public static final int RESPONSE_SET = 1;

    private Toolbar mToolbar;
    private RecyclerView mLocationsRecyclerView;
    private View mCurrentLocation;
    private SearchView mSearchView;
    private List<LocationResponse.Feature> mLocationsSuggestion;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> mAdapter;
    private LocationsAdapter mLocationsAdapter;
    private RealmResults<Location> mLocations;
    private View mProgressBar;
    private boolean fromSearch;
    private LocationSearchFragment mLocationSearchFragment;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        fromSearch = getIntent().getBooleanExtra(BUNDLE_FROM_SEARCH, false);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_locations);
        mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_actionbar);
        mCurrentLocation = findViewById(R.id.location_activity_current_location);
        mProgressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressBar);

        mLocationsRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.locationsList);
        mLocationsRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));

        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("");

        loadLocations();
        mLocationsAdapter = new LocationsAdapter();
        mLocationsRecyclerView.setAdapter(mLocationsAdapter);
        mLocationsRecyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());

        mLocationSearchFragment = new LocationSearchFragment();

        LocationHandler.getInstance().setLocationListener(new LocationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationFailure() {
                mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onLocationAchieved(Location location) {
                SSApp.getInstance().addLocation(location);
                loadLocations();
                mLocationsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                if (fromSearch) {
                    returnToCallingActivity();
                }
            }
        });

        findViewById(R.id.searchBtn).setOnClickListener(v -> {
            mLocationSearchFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "places");
        });
    }

    private void updateCurrentLocation() {
        LocationViewHolder locationViewHolder = new LocationViewHolder(mCurrentLocation);

        if (SSApp.getInstance().getLocation() != null) {
            locationViewHolder.bind(SSApp.getInstance().getLocation(), new LocationViewHolder.OnLocationItemOperation() {
                @Override
                public void onDeleteLocationClick(int position) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onDetailsChanged(int position, boolean inIsrael) {
                    updateIsInIsrael(SSApp.getInstance().getLocation(), inIsrael);
                }

                @Override
                public void onSetLocationClick(int position) {
                }
            });
        } else {
            locationViewHolder.bind(SSApp.getInstance().getLocation(), null);
        }
    }

    private void loadLocations() {
        mLocations = SSApp.getInstance()
                .getRealm()
                .where(Location.class)
                .equalTo("isActive", false)
                .findAll();

        updateCurrentLocation();
    }

    private void returnToCallingActivity() {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        setResult(RESPONSE_SET, intent);
        finish();
    }

    private void updateIsInIsrael(Location location, boolean inIsrael) {
        if (location.isInIsrael() != inIsrael) {
            SSApp.getInstance().getRealm().beginTransaction();
            location.setIsInIsrael(inIsrael);
            SSApp.getInstance().getRealm().commitTransaction();
            mLocationsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            updateCurrentLocation();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationSet(@NotNull ElavationService.LatLng latLng) {
        runOnUiThread(() -> {
            if (mLocationSearchFragment != null && mLocationSearchFragment.isVisible()) {
                mLocationSearchFragment.dismissAllowingStateLoss();
            }
            mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        });
        LocationHandler.getInstance()
                .setLocation(latLng.getLatitude(),
                        latLng.getLongitude(),
                        false
                );
    }

    class LocationsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<LocationViewHolder> implements LocationViewHolder.OnLocationItemOperation {

        @Override
        public LocationViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(LocationsActivity.this)
                    .inflate(R.layout.location_row, parent, false);
            return new LocationViewHolder(view);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(LocationViewHolder holder, int position) {
            holder.bind(mLocations.get(position), this);
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return mLocations == null ? 0 : mLocations.size();
        }

        @Override
        public void onDeleteLocationClick(int position) {
            SSApp.getInstance().removeLocation(mLocations.get(position));
            loadLocations();
            notifyItemRemoved(position);
        }

        @Override
        public void onSetLocationClick(int position) {
            SSApp.getInstance().setLocation(mLocations.get(position));
            returnToCallingActivity();
        }

        @Override
        public void onDetailsChanged(int position, boolean inIsrael) {
            updateIsInIsrael(mLocations.get(position), inIsrael);
        }
    }
}
```

For some reason it seems that it still look for it, but I have no idea why

Comment: Can you post the code of your `LocationsActivity` ?

Comment: @JuanDanielOrnella thank you, I posted my code now

Comment: Clean and rebuild your app, you might have some stale class files around.

Comment: By chance, in your build.gradle file do you have `minification` set to true on release? If so, try setting it to false and see if the issue persists. If that fixes it, respond back here and we can give more info on adding it back in without it breaking things.

Comment: @Silmarilos yes, of course I'm using pro-guard, but how would it affect that?

Comment: @laalto You were right. I can't believe I didn't try that before, such an embarrassment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You likely have some old files in your release build intermediates that are causing the issue, referencing code that is no longer there.

A clean rebuild should get rid of them.